# Uploading image from android app to Spring server

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-mvc, image-uploading

I have a problem with uploading image from android application to spring server. First of all i have this method on my server:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String fileUpload(@RequestBody MultipartFile file) {
    System.out.println("post image");
    try {
        // Get the file and save it somewhere
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
        System.out.println(bytes.length);

        //save file in server - you may need an another scenario
        Path path = Paths.get("file:///E:/together/images/" + file.getOriginalFilename());
        Files.write(path, bytes);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //redirect to an another url end point
    return "redirect";
}
```

And in my android app i'am get uri of image from image gallery and try call post method

```
FileEntity fileEntity = new FileEntity(new File(getRealPathFromURI(uri)), "application/octet-stream");
                        new Requests.Async().execute(fileEntity);
ublic static class Async extends AsyncTask<FileEntity,Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        restTemplate = RestTemplateSingleton.newInstance().getRestTemplate();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(FileEntity... uris) {
        try{
            restTemplate.postForObject(Requests.insertImage(),uris[0],FileEntity.class);
        }catch (HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException httpClientOrServerExc) {
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

but i get 500 http status when call this method. what's my mistake?

Comment: What does 500 mean?

Comment: `getRealPathFromURI(uri)` Please tell what it returned.

Comment: @greenapps getRealPathFromURI return path to image, 500 it's http status

Comment: You did not tell what 500 means. It is a status code. Yes. I know. But what does it mean?  And you did not tell what the path actually is. That it returns a path is evident. But what is the path exactly?

Comment: @greenapps i choose image from the gallery and return the path choosen image. For example: /storage/emulated/0/viber/media/Viber Images/IMG-9fc2fc1306a86c958fccf50b04b0ed8d-V.jpg